# Django form field validation and auth password validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm using Django 1.10.6 and working on a registration form. On a `forms.py` I want to use the `min_length` argument for the password form field to help prevent unnecessary server requests, because Django adds that attribute to the CSS and most browsers will check that before allowing a form to be submitted.

However, Django doesn't seem to like when I use [form field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/) along with [`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation) in certain cases. When I open up inspector on the registration page and delete the CSS for the `min_length` attribute of the password input (thus preventing being prompted by my browser to enter more characters) and submit the request with less than 8 characters, the form field validation fails and Django deletes/empties (sorry, not sure of the correct term) the cleaned data so the password is `None`, which then causes the rest of the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` to throw errors. This is the error which results `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Here's my registration class on forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=254,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'email'}))
    # when I remove the min_length here it works,
    # however I would like to have the benefit of the input's min_length being checked by the browser first
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", min_length=8,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password', 'type' : 'password'}))
    repassword = forms.CharField(label="Re-Enter Password",
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'repassword', 'type' : 'password'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('repassword')

        #validate that the two passwords match each other
        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

        # when the following 2 lines are uncommented
        # and I remove the min_length validator via inspector
        # and enter a password shorter than 8, password1 is None 
        # print(password1)
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

        validators = passwordValidation.get_default_password_validators()
        passwordValidation.validate_password(password1,User,validators)
```

Here are the validators found in `settings.py`

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        # I've tried this commented and uncommented, same results either way
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': { 'min_length' : 8 }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },

]
```

Is there a way that I can still have the client side min_length validation that the form field provides along with using the `validate_password` method?

**Edit** - Forgot to add that I can bypass this by individually calling each class found in [django.contrib.auth.password_validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/), but it seems like this is one of those situations where there's a standard way to do it but I'm not aware of it. For example...

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import CommonPasswordValidator
...
if CommonPasswordValidator().validate(password1):
    raise forms.ValidationError("Please choose another password")
```

Comment: do you remove max_length from form.Charfield when you add it down as validator

Comment: @iklinac yes and it works, but that defeats the purpose . I want it there so that Django would insert that attribute in the CSS of the input as I described at the top. Unless there's another way to add the `min_length` attribute to the input itself I'd prefer to keep it in the `form.Charfield` value

Comment: try to add it up in attrs dictionary instead :)

Comment: @iklinac awesome, it worked! Thanks. To be honest, I had been staring at it for so long that I didn't even notice it was part of the Charfield argument, not the widget!