# Accessing user object when creating a user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.10.6 and I'm working on a user registration form. During the validation process in my `forms.py` I'm trying to call the [`UserAttributeSimilarityValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/#UserAttributeSimilarityValidator) from within the clean method, but I'm having some trouble figuring out what the user object argument is that it requires. The request data is a QueryDict, not an object, so I'm confused as to what object I'm supposed to be using.

Here is the `UserAttributeSimilarityValidator` class found in the link I provided

```
class UserAttributeSimilarityValidator(object):
    DEFAULT_USER_ATTRIBUTES = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def __init__(self, user_attributes=DEFAULT_USER_ATTRIBUTES, max_similarity=0.7):
        self.user_attributes = user_attributes
        self.max_similarity = max_similarity

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if not user:
            return        

        for attribute_name in self.user_attributes:
            value = getattr(user, attribute_name, None)
            if not value or not isinstance(value, string_types):
                continue
            value_parts = re.split('\W+', value) + [value]
            for value_part in value_parts:
                if SequenceMatcher(a=password.lower(), b=value_part.lower()).quick_ratio() > self.max_similarity:
                    verbose_name = force_text(user._meta.get_field(attribute_name).verbose_name)
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _("The password is too similar to the %(verbose_name)s."),
                        code='password_too_similar',
                        params={'verbose_name': verbose_name},
                    )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _("Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information.")
```

Here's my clean method in `forms.py`

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')

    password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator().validate(password, USER_OBJET_HERE)
```

I tried to create a user object by using `namedtuple` like so

```
user = namedtuple('user', 'username email')
user_attributes = user(username = self.data.get('username'), email = self.data.get('email'))
password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator().validate(password1, user_attributes)
```

When I do this it fails with the following error `'user' object has no attribute '_meta'`. Is there an actual user object created by the form that I'm supposed to access, or am I supposed to create it like I attempted?

**UPDATE** I was way overthinking this and got it to work. I had to manually set the username and email attributes for the User object like so

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
User.username = self.data.get('username')
User.email = self.data.get('email')
```

Comment: why don't you just set it in AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS where it is intended to be set :)

Comment: @iklinac I tried that but had a separate issue that I couldn't get sorted out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437872/django-form-field-validation-and-auth-password-validation

Comment: Can I see your current AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS if you got any there

Comment: @iklinac sure, I'll update the other question that I linked since it's more relevant